# Save URL in anchor tag with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, save, save-as

I need to save a URL in an anchor tag on a page when a button is clicked. How can I do this with jQuery or pure JS?

If possible, can it "Save As" or otherwise name the file being saved from the URL a string that is on the page (from a specific heading tag with the id "heading", for instance)?

**EDIT**

To clarify:

```
<button id="button">Button</button>

<h1 id="heading">Website Title</h1>

<a href="http://website.com/sample.zip" id="file">File</a>
```

...how do I make it so that when the button is clicked it will automatically start downloading the ZIP file from the URL in the anchor tag?

Moreover, if possible, how do I have the file save with the name of the `H1` tag (i.e. "Website Title.zip")?

Answer (score 1):

If it is actually a .zip or a file with an extension that wouldn't normally be viewed in the browser, you can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<button id="button">Button</button>

<h1 id="heading">Website Title</h1>

<a href="http://website.com/sample.zip" id="file">File</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    window.location.assign($("#file").attr("href")); 
});
```

This will prompt you to download the file (in chrome it usually automatically starts the download) assuming that it can't be viewed by the browser. Not sure about the "save-as" part.

Comment: Not exactly, but please check the edit above for clarification.

Comment: @Charles Edited answer to hopefully be what you are looking for.

Comment: That essentially does it. Is there a way to set the name of the downloaded file to that of the heading?

Comment: @Charles not unless you use Chrome's <a download="my_file_name.zip">, but then you're narrowed to just Chrome.

Comment: <a href="http://website.com/sample.zip" id="file" download="Sample File.zip">File</a> ...running your code on that doesn't save it as "Sample File.zip" but "sample.zip". Is there a way to save it as "Sample File.zip"?

Comment: @Charles Yeah, do download="Sample_File.zip" with an underscore